Are these two sentences interchangeable? What is the difference?
１．荷物はここに置いてください。   

２．ここに荷物を置いてください。

What is the difference between these two sentences?
Is the location of the placing (ここに) interchangeable before or after the direct object?

You might have meant ここに置いてください, instead of ここで.

No, 荷物 is not the subject in either of these sentences. The particle は is the topic marker, it doesn't have to mark the subject necessarily. In both cases, 置いてください is referring to the person being spoken to (and that is the subject).
In the first sentence, the emphasis is on 荷物. You could translate it as "Regarding the luggage, please put it here." The object is implied to be 荷物. The second sentence has no particular emphasis and simply means "Please put the luggage here." and in this case, 荷物 is marked as the object by を.

No, in both cases 荷物 is the object.  Not sure I totally agree with that.  Semantically, yes, that's true.  But in the 荷物は sentence, I believe there technically is no object; it is implied (and we obviously know what it is).

Ah that is a good point, I guess you are right, let me modify my answer accordingly.

I'm not entirely sure I'm right, either.  I was hoping someone would confirm or refute my claim.

According to the last example of this answer, 荷物 would be the object in both cases, unless I misunderstood something.

It is the object, but it is still implied.
